# How to use Pipes on array query-parameters?

Tags: pipe, nestjs

I'm using nestjs to implement an http-endpoint that receives a set of uuids via a query-parameter.
How can I apply pipes such as `ParseUUIDPipe` to such an array query-parameter?

```js
@Get('test')
test(
  @Query('id', ParseArrayPipe, ParseUUIDPipe): id: string[],
) { ... }
```

`curl localhost/test?id=3b717319-e2c1-4807-a950-28b187661fe3&id=04500ae4-81b0-49ba-83f1-f9b69908f3ba`

---

When ever multiple query-parameters are send to the endpoint, the `ParseUUIDPipe` rejects the request with the following error.

```json
{
  "statusCode":400,
  "message":"The value passed as UUID is not a string",
  "error":"Bad Request"
}
```

---

How can we let the pipe validate the individual string values of the array, not the string-array as a whole?

Comment: read the spec of `ParseArrayPipe`: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/test/pipes/parse-array.pipe.spec.ts 

You cannot use `ParseUUIDPipe` because it expec an string, not an array